# Delete Custom Menu

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, c#

How is it possible to delete a custom root menu developed in VS?

I have gone through some walkthroughs and added an add-in that includes a button like so:

```xml
    <AddIn language="CLR" library="CustomUIElements.dll" namespace="CustomUIElements">
    <ArcMap>
      <Commands>
        <Button id="CustomUIElements_ZoomToLayerButton" 
          class="ZoomToLayerButton" 
          message="Zoom to selected layer" 
          caption="ZoomToLayer" 
          tip="Zoom to default extent" 
          category="Add-In Controls" 
          image="Images\ZoomToLayerButton.png">
          <Help heading="Zoom To Selected Layer">Set's the extent of selected layer</Help>
        </Button>        
      </Commands>
      <Menus>
        <Menu id="CustomUIElements_Zoom_Commands" caption="Zoom Commands" isRootMenu="true">
          <Items>
            <Button refID="CustomUIElements_ZoomToLayerButton" />
          </Items>
        </Menu>
      </Menus>
    </ArcMap>
  </AddIn>
```

Now ArcMap has the menu "Zoom Commands" but how do I remove it?

Comment: Seems that this can be solved by just running a 'Clean' on the solution in VS. The ArcGIS SDK seems to take care of unregistering and removing the menu from ArcMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I could just post my comment as an answer:

Perform a 'Clean' on the solution in Visual Studio. 
The ArcGIS SDK seems to take care of unregistering and removing the menu from ArcMap after the clean in Visual Studio has completed.